# With wicked gem, I can't manually move to the next step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, formwizard, wicked-gem

I am using the Wicked gem for multi-step forms and i plan on implementing a custom ajax method, so I will not be able to use the render_wizard method.  Right now I am just trying to manually move to the next step.  The following does not work:

```
def update
    jump_to next_step
    render step
end
```

I've also tried:

```
def update
    render next_step
end
```

but the step never actually changes.  So just putting "render next_step" keeps on calling the same step because "step" never changes

How do i manually move to the next step?

Comment: I would really have liked to know how to do this as I am having the same issue, wicked does not seem to be set up to work with ajax js.erb remote true very well.

Comment: I found a solution that worked for me. In the `form_with` that I am rendering I just specify the step like this `url: wicked_step(:my_step)` that way when the form gets reloaded by the js.erb file the partial can tell the form what step to submit to and then the controller just uses that step.

Answer (score -1):

Use a .js.erb view to respond to the AJAX command and then in the view, run the render_wizard in there:

```
$('#content').html('<%= j render_wizard @object %>');
```